# "Variable expected" and few more errors

Tags: java

I'm trying to fire a bullet in a 2D game. Depending on the desired target I selected with my mouse, x-axis speed and y-axis speed should change but should always sum up to the speed I fixed beforehand (which is 8) - every way that I try to do this I get an error.

I tried to fix my way into quite a few errors into this. I just don't know what to do at this point. I'm trying to solve this for 3 hours. Please help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie2tB.png

Comment: Put the code directly in the question, not an image of it. And you should state what the error is.

Comment: FYI, you can't write equations in your code and expect the compiler to solve them. You have to write the algorithm to populate those variables yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to make this line a comment `( yHiz )* (yHiz) + (xHiz ) * (xHiz) = 64;` because it doesn't do anything, at least, I don't think it does anything. Java thinks this is an error because it thinks you are trying to set a variable to 64, but you didn't pass in a variable.

Edit: Actually putting your code here instead of in an image would be better if you ask a question next time.